# how to display a Save Dialogbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, syncfusion

Hi i would like to display a save file dialog in my asp.net web page, user clicks a button and a save file dialog appears which allows user to save a diagram in his hard disk, how can I do it?

for saving diagram at server, i used

```
string AppPath = Server.MapPath(string.Empty);
DiagramWebControl1.SaveBinary(AppPath + @"\Test.edd");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do something like this on a postback button event:

```
     string filepath = AppPath + @"\Test.edd";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
     HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
              "attachment; filename=" + "Test.edd");
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
     HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
     HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```